# self signed certificate in certificate chain for postgressql, Prisma, and Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, prisma, ca

I'm trying to build DockerFile with Prisma to generate a PostgreSQL entity, but it's failing for CA Certificate, how do I add CA certificate?

```
[+] Building 60.6s (12/15)                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 236B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 338B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16                                                                               8.0s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node:16@sha256:...                      42.7s
 => => extracting sha256:...                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 342.87kB                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [ 2/11] RUN mkdir /code                                                                                                              0.7s
 => [ 3/11] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [ 4/11] COPY package*.json  ./                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [ 5/11] COPY prisma/schema.prisma ./                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 6/11] COPY .env ./                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 7/11] RUN npm i                                                                                                                    8.1s
 => ERROR [ 8/11] RUN npx prisma generate                                                                                                1.1s
```

### => ERROR [ 8/11] RUN npx prisma generate 1.1s

> [ 8/11] RUN npx prisma generate: #12 0.853 Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/4bc8b6e1b66cb932731fb1bdbbc550d1e010de81/linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x/libquery_engine.so.node.gz.sha256 failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

---

process "/bin/sh -c npx prisma generate" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1